# Is there any api available to get all resources in particular log analytics workspace using workspace id

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

powershell :

```
dataSources = Get-AzOperationalInsightsDataSource -Workspace $workspace -Kind AzureActivityLog
```

to list the resources.
is there any equivalent azure api are available?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer, as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent api is [Data Sources - List By Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/datasources/listbyworkspace).

You can nav to the link to find more details of it's usage.